# TypeScript ignore expression `if (object instanceof SomeClass)` inside `for(){}`? Or not?

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have code (see comments):

```ts
class ClassA
{
  propA: any;
}

class ClassB
{
  propB: any;
}

function fn( arr: (ClassA | ClassB)[] )
{
  for( let element of arr )
  {
    if( element instanceof ClassA )
    {
      element.propA = true; // Work as expected

      () =>
      {
        element.propA; // Unexpected error
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Message of unexpectedly error:

> Property 'propA' does not exist on type 'ClassA | ClassB'.
>
> Property 'propA' does not exist on type 'ClassB'.

When I remove the loop `for(){}`. Works as expected:

```ts
class ClassA
{
  propA: any;
}

class ClassB
{
  propB: any;
}

function fn( element: ClassA | ClassB )
{
  if( element instanceof ClassA )
  {
    element.propA = true; // Work as expected

    () =>
    {
      element.propA; // Work as expected
    }
  }
}
```

It's a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by [`aluanhaddad` - contributor TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13180):

> Your inner function is closing over a mutable binding that is scoped outside the `if` block and is thus not always going to be an instance of `ClassA`.
>
> To make this work, use a `const` binding:

```
function fn(arr: (ClassA | ClassB)[]) {
  for(const element of arr) {
```